# Using contextMenu on a dataTable inside a tab

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to add a contextMenu to a dataTable contained inside a tab.  I have been able to get the menu to show up on a dataTable which is not inside a tab and was also to get it to show up on the entire tab...but not specifically on the dataTable.

I've tried several different references in the 'for' attribute of the contextMenu...some blow up, some do not but the menu doesn't show up on right-click.

I'm using PrimeFaces 4.0.  Any suggestions?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="someForm">
        <p:tabView id="tv" var="tb" value="#{TempBeans.tabs}">
            <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{TempBeans.tabClose}"
                update="@form" />
            <p:tab id="tempTab" title="#{tb.name}" closable="true">
                <p:dataTable id="dTable" var="d" value="#{tb.dtbs}">
                    <p:column id="column1" headerText="name">
                        <h:outputText value="#{d.name}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column id="column2" headerText="id">
                        <h:outputText value="#{d.id}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
        <p:contextMenu for=":someForm:tv:dTable">
            <p:menuitem value="TableView" update="@form" icon="ui-icon-search" />
            <p:menuitem value="TableDelete" update="@form" icon="ui-icon-close" />
        </p:contextMenu>    
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried too put <p:contextMenu> inside <p:tab> ?

Comment: Look for errors in your javascript console

Comment: @Lamq I have tried the context menu inside the tab and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @kolossus The javascript console is empty

Comment: when you have put the contextMenu into the tab have you change the for to for="dTable" ? With contextMenu outside tab the for will be for=":idform:idtab:iddatatable" so in your case for=":someForm:tempTab:dTable" it's working with this  ?

Comment: @Lamq I did change the for to "dTable" when I moved it into the tab and it didn't work.  The page renders but the menu doesn't show on right-click.  When I have the context menu outside the the tabview and use the for you specified the page fails to render with "Cannot find component with expression ":someForm:tempTab:dTable" referenced from "someForm:cMenuId""...I have also made the change of assigning the id of "cMenuId" to the contextMenu as you can see in the error.

Comment: @Lamq I have also tried the for string of ":someForm:tv:tempTab:dTable" with the contextMenu outside the tabView and it fails to render with "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: tempTab"

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to get the context menu to appear by changing the table to be selectable...which is sort of what I wanted anyway.  However, now I have another problem...If I make the selectionMode "multiple" and use ctrl-clicks to select rows it seems to register the last right-click as a single click.

1. click one row
2. ctrl-click second row
3. ctrl-click third row
4. right-click one of the rows...deselects other rows

So it seems I would have to force my users to:

1. click one row
2. ctrl-click second row
3. ctrl-right-click third row

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAARRRRGH!! Deal-breaker...looks like I'm going back to prehistoric ui times and implementing multiple selection with checkboxes.

Please someone tell me I'm wrong and there's a simple way to make it not behave like this.

Anyway, here is how I eventually managed to get a contextMenu to show up:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form id="someForm">
        <p:tabView id="tv" var="tb" value="#{TempBeans.tabs}">
            <p:ajax event="tabClose" listener="#{TempBeans.tabClose}" update="@form" />
            <p:tab id="tempTab" title="#{tb.name}" closable="true">
                <p:dataTable id="dTable" var="d" value="#{tb.dtbs}" selection="#{tb.selectedDTBs}" selectionMode="multiple" rowKey="#{d.name}">
                    <p:column id="column1" headerText="name">
                        <h:outputText value="#{d.name}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column id="column2" headerText="id">
                        <h:outputText value="#{d.id}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
                <p:contextMenu id="cMenuId" for="dTable">
                    <p:menuitem value="TableView" update="@form" icon="ui-icon-search" />
                    <p:menuitem value="TableDelete" update="@form" icon="ui-icon-close" />
                </p:contextMenu>
            </p:tab>
        </p:tabView>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```